# PHP function - Shuffling / making a special word to always be the first in a string

Tags: php, string

I have a list of dozens of simple sentences/strings. Each sentence contains a special keyword. My task is to make sure this special keyword is ALWAYS as the first word of the sentence.

Let's assume my special keyword is: dog.

**Example sentences *BEFORE*:**

```
$string1='my dog is eating soup';
$string2='where have you seen my dog last time';
$string3='this little dog barks a lot';
$string4='most cats are better than my dog';
```

**Sentences that should be *AFTER*:**

```
dog my is eating soup
dog where have you seen my last time
dog this little barks a lot
dog most cats are better than my
```

---

I see there is str_shuffle PHP function but it shuffles words in a string randomly; I need to make sure that my special keyword (dog) is always first in sentence. And ideally this function should be as fast as possible since there are lots of such operations to complete.

NOTE - I only need an example on how to do it on one sentence, not all..

Comment: Is it possible, that the keyword is more than once in the sentence?

Comment: There could only be one special word in each sentence (if checking for multiple instances is faster then whatever faster is better though ;)

Comment: Where do you store that strings? Some file?

Comment: This question is not really on topic. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Strings are stored in a PHP string, like:

$string='my dog is eating soup'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just simply remove the keyword in the string with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and append it at the start of the string, e.g.

```
<?php

    $str = "my dog is eating soup";
    $keyword = "dog";

    echo $newString = $keyword . " " . str_replace($keyword, "", $str);

?>
```

output:

```
dog my is eating soup
```

Comment: Will produce undesired results if the keyword doesn't exist (it will after you run this)